# How to swap rows by just swapping the first cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

Say I have this table:

[image]

Occasionally I need to swap and add rows to reorganize my table. In this example, I put the row `Cat` at the bottom, and insert row `Horse`:

[image]

And then later decide to move row `Mouse` to the bottom again, and leave row 3 empty:

[image]

For convenience I just cut/copy/paste/move/insert the names only, and expect that the program understands that what I mean is to cut/copy/paste/move/insert the whole rows. Is there a way to make it understand that?

I can use any spreadsheet software.

---

Edit: I realize that I can select the whole row by pressing <kbd>Shift + Space</kbd>. This can be the answer for now. However, I'd like to leave this question open if anyone wants to go the hard way. This would benefit everyone.

Comment: Honestly it's hypothetical kind of issue,, since patter is not fixed,, what would be next addition and on what basis,, I mean any criteria,,, one possibility ,, enter Rows in Random order then Sort in Ascending order and leave certain row between !!

Comment: Why don't you make a selection of all cells in the table, and simply press the sort button? It will do exactly what you want with the press of one button. If you want to sort on anything but column A, Make your selection, then press TAB to move inside the selection until the preferred column has the active cell in it, then press the sort button to sort on that column.

Comment: @LPChip no, my organization is quite arbitrary. One can only sort it manually

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cut/copy/paste/insert etc just the name, select the entire row by clicking on the numbered row header first, then do your action to move the entire row all day once.

Comment: I know. I want to use keyboard and avoid mouse as much as possible

Comment: Shift+space will select the entire row, then you can Ctrl+x and so on.